# How to send simple alerts or strings via WIFI with an Arduino and CC3000?

Tags: arduino, wifi, ip-address, message

I'm kinda new to this forum.

I have an Arduino UNO and a CC3000 wifi shield from Adafruit.I want to send messages to a laptop or specfic IP address via wifi. Not complex messages or anything, just an alert or a flag. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm not really sure of the protocol for sending something like this, or where I would even be sending it to.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a CC3000 WiFi Shield and made a temperature plotter which you can read about [here](http://steveorrichio.com/temperature-and-humidity-sensor-with-live-stream/).

But, I think you could configure your Arduino as a webserver (there are pre-made sketches with the examples) and figure out a way to install PHP on it for it's mailing function? You could also look at services such as Zapier and IFTTT to send emails/text message alerts to you.

[For a PHP tutorial using pcduino](http://learn.linksprite.com/pcduino/php/use-php-serial-class-to-communicate-to-arduino-uno-from-pcduino/).

This type of project I think would be better suited for a Raspberry Pi since it's already Internet ready.

I hope this will point you in a better direction.